# extra info in android makefiles

Tags: android, android-ndk, makefile

I'm trying to get some information about my Android Makefile, but echo doesn't work for printting messages.

Is there any way of printting a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always forget how to do this kind of things.

Try this:

```
$(warning LOCAL_PATH is '$(LOCAL_PATH)')
```

I always use some comment in my makefiles on top:

```
# include $(CLEAR_VARS) change PATH! If you use it, before save PATH
# Extra info using ndk-build V=1
# Debug info using ndk-build -d
# Echo variables $(warning LOCAL_PATH is '$(LOCAL_PATH)')
# SRC_FILES := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Android/jni/*.cpp)
# Execute ndk-build NDK_LOG=1 to extra info before compilation
```

Comment: There is also `ndk-build NDK_LOG=1` which can be combined with `V=1`

Answer (score 1):

If a goal is `DUMP_xxx` then ndk-build dumps a variable `xxx` instead of building anything, e.g.

```
ndk-build APP_ABI=mips DUMP_LOCAL_CFLAGS
```

This will print the variable `$(LOCAL_CFLAGS)` and stop.

Answer (score 0):

`$(info $(LOCAL_PATH))` is more generic